# How to access a JSON object of nested structure sent by Angular to Spring boot backend?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have a post http request from angular having a folllowing JSON structure :

```
   {
       "abc":{
               "pqr":2,
               "lmn":5,
               "xyz":89
             },
       "def":[a,b,c,d],
       "klm":{
               //object attributes
             }
   }
```

which gets sent as a post request from angular HttpClient.

Now in spring boot Controller I am accepting it using a Hashmap of

```
@PostMapping("/createXyzFunctionality")
    public void createXyzFunctionality(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json)
    {
      for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : json.entrySet())
      {
        //Using entry.getKey() and entry.getValue() I can access the attributes 
        //"abc","def","klm" as string but I want to access as class objects
        .....
      }
    }
```

Now, I have a model class for "abc" but isn't exactly the instance of my class, so when I do

```
CustomClass val = (CustomClass) entry.getValue();
```

I got ClassCastException, Help me access the attributes of the Objects in hashmap without changing the models in spring boot.

```
CustomClass{
      private Integer pqr,lmn,xyz;
      private String extraVariable;
      //getters setters
}
```

I want pqr,lmn,xyz to get values from "abc".

Comment: Mapping objects to specific classes is generally a good idea.

Comment: @Carsten I assume you wanted to write "... NOT a good idea"?

Comment: @Endzeit lol no. Where on earth would you get that idea?

Comment: @Carsten I think there is a misunderstanding. I think you are talking about mapping JSON-Objects to specific classes instead of the Object class. I thought you meant casting Object to specific classes was a good idea. I doubt that casting is a good idea and should be circumvented where applicable. I agree that you should use specific classes and in general strong typing. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json` you should expect an object of the class in `RequestBody`.

So create a set of DTOs:

```
public class BodyClass {
    private Abc abc;
    private List<String> def;
    private Klm klm;
    //getters & setters
}
public class Abc {
    private Integer pqr;
    private Integer lmn;
    private Integer xyz;
}
public class Klm {
    //some parameters, getters & setters
}
```

And accept `@RequestBody BodyClass bodyClass`, e.g.:

```
@PostMapping("/createXyzFunctionality")
public void createXyzFunctionality(@RequestBody BodyClass bodyClass) {
    //your logic here
}
```

`bodyClass` will contain all the attributes of the JSON you're sending.